# Google maps API, cannot clear previous route

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Below is the function i'm using to generate a route from a given point. I have several places where a user can request directions from... if the user requests directions for a 2nd time then the 1st route is still displayed on the map, obviously this does not look good. How can I remove it?

```
base.getRoute = function(start, la, lo) {

        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        directionsDisplay.setMap(base.map);
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("drivingDirectionsPanel"));

        start+=",uk";
        var end = new google.maps.LatLng(la, lo);
        var request = {
                origin: start,
                destination: end,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };

        directionsService.route(request, function(response,status) {
            if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {


                $('#drivingDirectionsPanel').html('');
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

                $('html, body').animate({ 
                      scrollTop: $('#drivingDirectionsPanel').offset().top 
                  }, 1500);

            } else {
                alert("There was a problem finding directions");
            }
        });         
    };
```

I have tried adding a

```
directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
```

but this does not work.

Any ideas guys? Thanks

Comment: it is not plural, it is singular `direction**s**Display.setMap(null);`, remove the s.

Answer (score 1):

Make directions display a 'class' or a global variable so it will clear the panel when it renders the directions reaponse.

Comment: sorry, not sure what you mean? can you provide more detail please?

Comment: You are creating a new directions display object everytime you getRoute(). You should create one with a broader scope either in the opening script tag or inside your object oriented javascript function. That way you can actually clear the display with a reference to the object thats actually displaying the panel.

Comment: Thanks Rick, I think I get you. Any chance of a quick example using my code?

Comment: OK, I got the map clearing.. thanks Rick. I moved the variables to outside of the functions (at the top). Only problem now is when the user try's to get a 2nd a second set of directions the start point is not correct, it always picks the same random location. It looks like the 'start' variable is not getting data the 2nd time around?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i did it:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
$.extend(map,{
    pv: {
        markerArray: [],
        areaCircle: null,
        userLocation: {
            latitude: 38.68551,
            longitude: -98.789062
        },
        removeAllMarkers: function(){
            for (var i = 0; i < this.markerArray.length; i++) {
                if (this.markerArray[i].directions) this.markerArray[i].directions.setMap(null);
                this.markerArray[i].setMap(null);
            }
        },
        removeAllDirections: function(){
            for (var i = 0; i < this.markerArray.length; i++) {
                if (this.markerArray[i].directions) this.markerArray[i].directions.setMap(null);
            }
        },
        geocoder: new google.maps.Geocoder(),
        directions: new google.maps.DirectionsService(),
        directionPanel: document.getElementById('directions'),
        center: null
    }
});
```

Now any time i add a marker, i add a reference to it inside of markerArray, then when i want to remove all directions or all markers, i simply call `map.pv.removeAllDirections()` or `map.pv.removeAllMarkers()`

Answer (score 0):

```
directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
map.setZoom(8);
map.setCenter();
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work using the combination of the solutions suggested above.  So the "directionsDisplay" needs to be global and then directionsDisplay.setMap(null) needs to be called before you create directionsDisplay another time and it will clear the previous route from the map.

Here is the code:

```
    if(directionsDisplay != undefined) 
        directionsDisplay.setMap(null);

    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({preserveViewport:true});
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('dvDirResults'));

    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            $('#<%= lblGetDirError.ClientID %>').hide();
            $('#dvDirResults').html("");
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            map.panToBounds(response.routes[0].bounds);
            map.setCenter(response.routes[0].bounds.getCenter()); 
            //map.fitBounds(response.routes[0].bounds);
            if(map.getZoom() < 10) map.setZoom(10);
        }
        else
            $('#<%= lblGetDirError.ClientID  %>').show();
    });
```